# VSCode can't find ndk react-native

Tags: android, react-native, android-ndk

I have a simple react-native project when I try to build an android release version of the application, I face this error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: NDK not configured. Download
> it with SDK manager. Preferred NDK version is '21.4.7075529'

I made a Keystore and set password like android studio to get a release and debug apk.

I tried this until now:

- I tried to set NDK in android studio but couldn't build the project.
- I also modified build.gradle to build the project but was unsuccessful.

I put my singingConfig and buildTypes and also stackTrace below.

[my keystore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxNh3.jpg)
[singingConfig and buildTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy0LM.png)

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: NDK not configured. Download it with SDK manager. Preferred NDK version is '21.4.7075529'.
> > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

Answer (score 0):

- Open root folder projectname > android > open local.properties > copy and paste below lines after `sdk.dir` (if you don't have a local.properties file copy the below file and change SDK path according to your operating system.)

```
sdk.dir=/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk
```

- ndk.dir=/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 (You should find this version in the NDK folder and the path will vary depending on your operating system.);

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using another way to get release version of the apk.
I used `eas build -p android` or `expo build:android` and finally after a really long time expo generates apk on his website. But it was too large application about 60mg and I'm trying to reduce it's size.

`eas build -p android` this command is for abb version
`expo build:android` this is for apk release.
but unfortunately, I Couldn't use gradle in order to release apk.